# Recommended BatchSize for dealing with total x milion transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, ado.net, batch-processing

Goal:
Handle a big batchsize based on total 3 million transaction (at least 3 milion) without any error or bug.

Problem:
How much can batchsize contain in order make a transaction based on total transaction of 3 million?
I don't want any bug or similiar during the process time of dealing with total of 3 milion transaction.

Info:
*The code is a sample and in reality the size is much bigger.
*The data is dummy.
*The total transaction can be larger size than 3 milion.

Thank you!

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static int _loop = 20000; // 20 000 transaction


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Test> listOfTest = new List<Test>();

            for (int i = 0; i < _loop; i++)
            {
                var price = NextDecimal(new Random());
                var rank = new Random().Next(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);

                Test test = new Test(price, rank);

                listOfTest.Add(test);
            }

            InsertData(listOfTest);         
        }


        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return
                "Data Source=" +
                "Initial Catalog=Test;" +
                "Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        }


        private static void InsertData(List<Test> listOfTest)
        {
            const string queryConst = "INSERT INTO dbo.TestTbl (Price, Rank) " +
                                      "VALUES ";

            const int batchMaxSize = 5;

            string query = queryConst;

            var sep = "";
            var batchSize = 0;

            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", cn))
            {
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < listOfTest.Count; i++)
                    {
                        batchSize++;

                        query += $@"{sep}(@Price{i}, @Rank{i})";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price" + i.ToString(), SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = listOfTest[i].Price;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Rank" + i.ToString(), SqlDbType.Int).Value = listOfTest[i].Rank;
                        sep = ",";

                        if ((batchSize == batchMaxSize) || ((i + 1) == listOfTest.Count))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandText = query;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                            batchSize = 0;

                            query = queryConst;
                            sep = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
                {
                    string msg = "Insert Error:";
                    msg += ex.Message;
                    throw new Exception(msg);
                }
                finally
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
            }
        }


        public static decimal NextDecimal(this Random rng)
        {
            byte scale = (byte)rng.Next(29);
            bool sign = rng.Next(2) == 1;

            return new decimal(rng.NextInt32(),
                               rng.NextInt32(),
                               rng.NextInt32(),
                               sign,
                               scale);
        }

        public static int NextInt32(this Random rng)
        {
            int firstBits = rng.Next(0, 1 << 4) << 28;
            int lastBits = rng.Next(0, 1 << 28);
            return firstBits | lastBits;
        }
    }


    public class Test
    {
        public Test(decimal price, int rank)
        {
            this.Price = price;
            this.Rank = rank;
        }

        public decimal Price{ get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTbl]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Price] [decimal](38, 5) NULL,
    [Rank] [int] NULL
)
```

Comment: Loads of tiny transactions is going to be slow whatever you do. Scrap the lot and use `SqlBulkCopy`.

Comment: I agree with @Charlieface you'll get much better throughput using SqlBulkCopy or anther method to insert many rows at once (i.e. INSERT...SELECT from a TVP or OPENJSON.